# border layout code breaking, not able to see the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

- I have hbox layout, where in the left it shows tree and on the right
  it shows tabs.
- But the problem is I should not use hbox, but I should use border
  layout.
- When I use two column layout code is breaking.
- Providing my code with hbox layout.
- Can you guys tell me how to make the below code work in border
  layout.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border

I am trying to change border in the below part of code

```
var createTreeAndContentPanel = function(tree) {
        var retval,
            contentPanel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs, if you are using a "Border" layout, at least one of the child panel has to use region : "center".
So you need to apply `region : center` on your panel containing tabs, and `region : west` to your panel containing tree.

[image]

Finally you need to add these 2 panels inside a parent panel with a `layout: border`

From doc :

> Any Container using the Border layout must have a child item with region:'center'. The child item in the center region will always be resized to fill the remaining space not used by the other regions in the layout.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you update in my code its confusing

Comment: I pasted your code in code base, its not showing up, i dont see any js error, what problem could be

Comment: Actually your code wasnt really clear to me ☺ all the informations I gave you are enough.  It s up to you now ☺

Comment: can you give ur gmail id, we can do screenshare

Comment: its working fine now since I didn't add width and height